# Forcing SWITCH to process all statements or break if case match [StateMachine]

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Let's say I need to go through bunch of statements and process each case, results of which will be "incrementation" of IntVar. So like:

```
int result = 1;
if (condition1)
{
   result = result + 2;
}
if (condition2)
{
   result++;
}
if (condition3)
{
   result++;
}
//things get hairy
if (result != 5 && condition4)
{
   result++;
}
if (result != 5 && condition5)
{
   result++;
}
// do a thing based on a result value
```

I' love to use while{} here but I can't because `result` can be less than 5 when all cases processed. What i had in mind is putting all the checks into SWITCH and make continue to process them until the end (and then continue code normally) UNLESS `result` hits "5" middle way, then just go straight to result process.

Is it possible to force default SWITCH to do so without writing custom one and/or overcomplicating things too much?

Comment: If you are using C# 7.0, [Switch statements with patterns](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) feature is available.

Comment: I'm using Unity 5.3.4f1, which seems to use NET 2.0.x so it means C# v2.x

Comment: `switch` statement always picks the matching `case` and **doesn't** fall through

Comment: You could certainly use some abstraction, but it won't reduce complexity, unless you manage to simplify logic. But it's hard to suggest anything due to very abstract example. 4 and 5 are depend on 1, 2 and 3, but it's unclear why you compare with 5. Does it means that **all** conditions (1, 2 and 3) are true? And then you are checking for it again in 5. Pretty obscured logic if you ask me (with optimization probably).

Comment: Yeah, that result check for 5 seems pointless, I just was writing simple example. The short story is I want to increment the `result` variable as long as the condition for each case is met and stop if it reached max value I have in mind (5 in this example case). There is no point to go through other conditions if I already reached max.

Comment: You could use a functional approach using a list of `Func` and by how much to increase if `true`, and then loop through it, but that would require .net 3.5 at least